# How to make a bot talk conversationally using Pyrogram on Telegram

Tags: testing, bots, telegram, pyrogram

I wrote a bot using [Python Telegram Bot](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot). Then, i wanted to write some automatic tests for it. And that's the problem: i needed a way to send messages, wait for my bot to reply, and then react to those messages (either sending more text or clicking on buttons).

Well, i didn't found a good answer for it online.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to test a bot from the user-side?

There it tgintegration out there, which seems to be doing exactly what you want:
https://github.com/JosXa/tgintegration

Comment: This is valid too. But, although i dont remember why, i tested tgIntegration but something was off. I dont know if was something realted to packaging or it did not met my needs. But i will upvote this because it is a valid solution for other people!

Comment: Actually i'm even going to test it again when i have some time

Answer (score 0):

So i had to crack my head and think on something on my own. Maybe it is not the better, or the most performatic, but solved ALL my problems, and in a clean way.

So my idea was to use a Producer-Consumer schema where i set somehwere to store all my updates and the tests were the consumer. Further, i decided to use an [Asyncio Queue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-queue.html). It has methods to hang up and wait for items to be stored on queue. Exactly what i needed.

Now, some code. First of all, i created a CustomQueue class, extending from Asyncio.Queue where i could implement some functions like `skip_n_messages` or `discard_n_messages`, to keep my code DRY.

CustomQueue:

```py
class CustomQueue(Queue):
    """
        I made this custom class so i could handle different situations 'elegantly'(the functions below)
    """
    async def skip_n_messages(self, n: int):
        """
            Skips N messages on queue and returns message N + 1
        """
        await self.discard_n_messages(n)
        return await self.get()

    async def discard_n_messages(self, n: int):
        """
            Discards N messages from Queue
        """
        for _ in range(n):
            await self.get()
```

Now, i need to set somewhere that i want all the incoming messages to be put on CustomQueue. Because i writing tests, i wrote it on a [fixture](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/fixture.html):

```py
@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def message_queue(pyro_client: Client) -> CustomQueue:
    message_queue = CustomQueue()

    @pyro_client.on_message(filters.text & filters.private)
    @pyro_client.on_edited_message(filters.text & filters.private)
    async def queuer(client: Client = None, message: Message = None):
        debug(f"Message received: {message.text}")
        debug(f"Queue size before: {message_queue.qsize()}")
        await message_queue.put(message)
        debug(f"Message queued. New queue size: {message_queue.qsize()}")

    return message_queue
```

Now, some use cases:

```py
async def test_command_echo(pyrogram_client: Client, message_queue: CustomQueue):
    await pyro_client.send_message(TEST_TARGET_USERNAME, f"/echo Is someone there?")
    # The function will hold in this line until the message is received
    incoming_message: Message = await message_queue.get_message()
    assert incoming_message.text == "Is someone there?"
```

Now, to the downside: I really really don't know if this schema supports concurrent updates. An workaround would be setting a message_queue for each command, by setting up some update filters, but i never tested this (since my bot is written with another library)